# background-image fixed no iOS

Tags: html5

Criei um background com imagem fixa no body do site. Ficou ok no desktop e no Android, mas no iOS a imagem não fica fixa. A imagem rola pra baixo conforme desço o conteúdo.

Comment: Rodrigo coloque o código HTML/CSS que vc tem por favor.

Comment: Primeiro, tinha feito somente uma linha e funcionou em tudo, menos no iOS:

body {
   background: url(img/bg.png) repeat-x fixed; 
  }

Depois, incluí um media query, e continuou não funcionando:


  
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
   body {
    background: url(img/bg-mobile.png) fixed no-repeat; 
    background-color: #9A7350;
   }
  }

Comment: Rodrigo como te falei, se possível coloque o seu código inteiro HTML coma `<head>` inclusive e o CSS todo. Só com essas informações não da para te dar uma resposta precisa. Edite sua pergunta com os códigos ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente o iOS não dá suporte para o `background-attachment: fixed;`. Não consegui encontrar uma documentação oficial, mas existe muita discussão sobre o assunto. Em meio a todas as discussões, o certo é que fundo fixo não funciona no iOS.

No entanto existem algumas *gambiarras* que <s>resolvem</s> podem amenizar o problema, mas o efeito não é nem de perto o mesmo que o normal. Uma delas é usar JavaScript para fazer o *background* acompanhar o *scroll* da tela. Seria:

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundPosition = '0 '+window.pageYOffset+'px';
});
```

```css
body{
   background: url(https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
Role para baixo
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
fim!
```

Comment: Legal, funcionou no iOS, mas agora "bugou" no Android e no desktop. :(

Comment: Agora foi! No lugar de no-repeat, coloquei  repeat-x; e, no media query, coloquei background: url(img/bg-mobile.png) no-repeat; background-color: #9A7350;

Comment: @RodrigoItaborahy No desktop funciona normal, é só executar o snippet acima.

Answer (score 0):

Eu gostaria de ver o seu código para saber qual seria a melhor opção para o seu caso. Mas como não temos demais detalhes assim como o @dvd  vou postar uma solução só com CSS sem JavaScript e crossbrowser. *Apesar do notório problema do `background-attachment:fixed;` nos iPhone também não achei documentação oficial.*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
body {
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/800/800);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <h1>início</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>Fim</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: hugocsl, já consegui com a dica do dvd. Adradeço pela atençaõ, de qualquer forma.

Comment: Se vc usou a resposta do @dvd vc deveria aceitar a resposta dele e não a minha rss. De qq forma boa sorte com o projeto

Comment: É que eu testei as duas e não sabia que só poderia marcar uma (sou novo aqui). Obrigado!